# Removing Brackets but leave CDATA untouched

Tags: php, cdata

Is it possible to remove the brackets inside but leave the CDATA Tag untouched? How?

```
<![CDATA[

This is some Text with [brackets inside]

]]>
```

Edit: I use PHP, sorry.

Edit II: I see I can use lookaround assertions but are a bit unaware how to do the AND connecter that the opening bracket may be either before or after CDATA and how to connect the last two chunks.

Comment: Uh, if you use PHP, then why don't you want to use lookaround assertions? That's *exactly*  what they're for...

Comment: How would it look like in PHP? I was not aware that it's there in PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the regex you will need:

```
$subject = 'your_input_text';
$matchPattern = '/(<!\[CDATA\[[^[]*)\[(.*?)\]([^\]]*\]\]>)/s';
$replacePattern = '$1$2$3';
$result = preg_replace($matchPattern, $replacePattern, $subject);
```

You can see the results **[here](http://regexr.com?323du)**.

And here's the explanation of regex pattern:

```
# (<!\[CDATA\[[^\[]*)\[(.*?)\]([^\]]*\]\]>)
# 
# Options: dot matches newline
# 
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(<!\[CDATA\[[^\[]*)»
#    Match the characters “<!” literally «<!»
#    Match the character “[” literally «\[»
#    Match the characters “CDATA” literally «CDATA»
#    Match the character “[” literally «\[»
#    Match any character that is NOT a [ character «[^\[]*»
#       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
# Match the character “[” literally «\[»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.*?)»
#    Match any single character «.*?»
#       Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
# Match the character “]” literally «\]»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «([^\]]*\]\]>)»
#    Match any character that is NOT a ] character «[^\]]*»
#       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
#    Match the character “]” literally «\]»
#    Match the character “]” literally «\]»
#    Match the character “>” literally «>»
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// uses MFC CString syntax but any string library will have the same essential functions

CString myCDATA;
CString workString;
int iTagStart;

iTagStart = String.Find("<![CDATA[") + 9 // 9 = length of "<![CDATA["
// get the string without the endpoints
workString = CString.Mid(iTagStart,myCDATA.GetLength() - 9 - 3); // 3 = length of "]]>"
workString.Replace("[","");
workString.Replace("]","");
// reassemble
myCDATA = "<![CDATA[" + workString + "]]>";
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but there are multiple CDATA Sections in my Document, hence this would not work.